# Why is the difference between oldolduname and uname?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls

Why is the difference between oldolduname and uname?

I have been reading the man pages and I don't get the subtlety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you call `uname` from userspace, you do not need to care about the difference, and there should be no need to use olduname or oldolduname. From userspace, you use `struct utsname` and you call the `uname()` function.

From the man page:

> Over time, increases in the size of the utsname structure have led to
>   three successive versions of uname(): sys_olduname() (slot
>   __NR_oldolduname), sys_uname() (slot __NR_olduname), and sys_newuname() (slot __NR_uname). The first one used length 9 for all
>   fields; the second used 65; the third also uses 65 but adds the
>   domainname field. The glibc uname() wrapper function hides these
>   details from applications, invoking the most recent version of the
>   system call provided by the kernel.

So, throughout history the sizes and content of `struct utsname` has changed slightly, and the kernel has kept 3 different versions around to keep compatibility with userspace, you can see the different versions that the kernel handles here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/utsname.h?v=2.6.38#L24 . However glibc, or any C library on linux hides all this from you.

Answer (score 1):

`uname` is the function called by user code.

It calls one of the kernel functions `sys_newuname`, `sys_uname`, or `sys_olduname`, depending on the version of the Linux kernel. The difference between these is the lengths of the name fields (9 characters in `sys_olduname`, 65 characters in the other two), and `sys_newuname` adds an additional `domainname` field to the structure.